# Возникает javafx.fxml.LoadException

Tags: java, javafx, исключения, fxml

Структура проекта:
[image: Структура проекта]

Терминал:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/D:/User/OneDrive/Documents/Labs/Lab78/out/production/Lab78/sample/view/main.fxml

at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2595)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3237)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
at sample.controller.LoginController.showMainScreen(LoginController.java:55)
at sample.controller.LoginController.lambda$initialize$0(LoginController.java:41)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8890)
at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:206)
at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3862)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1849)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2590)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:409)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:299)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:447)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:412)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:446)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2591)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
    at sample.DataFileHandler.fillGuests(DataFileHandler.java:28)
    at sample.controller.MainController.initialize(MainController.java:61)
    ... 65 more
```

LoginController.java

```
package sample.controller;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import sample.Config;
import sample.animations.Fade;
import sample.animations.Move;

import java.io.IOException;

import static sample.Main.primaryStage;

public class LoginController {

    @FXML
    private Button loginButton;

    @FXML
    private PasswordField loginPassword;

    @FXML
    private Button incorrectPasswordButton;

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        loginButton.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
            String enteredPassword = loginPassword.getText().trim();
            if (!enteredPassword.equals(Config.ADMIN_PASSWORD)) {
                loginPassword.clear();
                Fade buttonFade = new Fade(incorrectPasswordButton, 300, 0f, 1f, 1, false);
                buttonFade.fade();
                incorrectPasswordButton.setVisible(true);
                Move buttonMove = new Move(incorrectPasswordButton, 300, false, 0f, 10f, 1, false);
                buttonMove.move();
            } else {
                try {
                    showMainScreen();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        incorrectPasswordButton.setOnAction(actionEvent -> incorrectPasswordButton.setVisible(false));
    }

    private void showMainScreen() throws IOException {

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/sample/view/main.fxml"));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    }

}
```

В showMainScreen() пробовал загружать через getResourseAsStream(), но результат всегда null.

main.fxml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0"
            style="-fx-background-color: #2196f3;"
            fx:controller="sample.controller.MainController">
    <TableView fx:id="guestsTable" prefHeight="315.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: #6ec6ff;">
      <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="nameColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Name"/>
          <TableColumn fx:id="passportColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Passport ID"/>
          <TableColumn fx:id="roomColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Room"/>
          <TableColumn fx:id="entryDateColumn" prefWidth="75.0" text="Entry Date"/>
          <TableColumn fx:id="evictionDateColumn" prefWidth="83.199951171875" text="Eviction Date"/>
      </columns>
        <columnResizePolicy>
          <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY"/>
        </columnResizePolicy>
    </TableView>
    <Button fx:id="checkInButton" layoutX="7.0" layoutY="326.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="26.0"
            prefWidth="140.0" style="-fx-background-color: #0069c0;" text="Check In Guest" textFill="WHITE"/>
    <Button fx:id="editButton" layoutX="156.0" layoutY="326.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="26.0"
            prefWidth="140.0" style="-fx-background-color: #F3A712;" text="Edit Guest" textFill="WHITE"/>
    <Button fx:id="invoiceButton" layoutX="305.0" layoutY="326.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="26.0"
            prefWidth="140.0" style="-fx-background-color: #018E42;" text="Prepare an Invoice" textFill="WHITE"/>
    <Button fx:id="searchRoomsButton" layoutX="305.0" layoutY="363.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="26.0"
            prefWidth="140.0" style="-fx-background-color: #0069c0;" text="Search Free Rooms" textFill="WHITE"/>
    <Button fx:id="searchGuestButton" layoutX="156.0" layoutY="363.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="26.0"
            prefWidth="140.0" style="-fx-background-color: #0069c0;" text="Search Guest" textFill="WHITE"/>
    <Button fx:id="lockButton" layoutX="453.0" layoutY="326.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="26.0"
            prefWidth="140.0" style="-fx-background-color: #bf1a2f;" text="Lock System" textFill="WHITE"/>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1

Comment: Обратите внимание - Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
    at sample.DataFileHandler.fillGuests(DataFileHandler.java:28)
    at sample.controller.MainController.initialize(MainController.java:61)